# scikit k-means: Find data-points that belong to resulting cluster of specific centroids

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

So, I have the following snippet working on k-means to generate 2 clusters.
Though, we are able to find the centroids of the 2 resulting clusters and the count of how many data-points belong to each cluster-label, 
Is there a way to know data points of each cluster whose centroid is a specific value or greater than a value.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(100)
# print(x)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
# km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, verbose=1)

estimator = km.fit(x.reshape(-1,1))
print("centroids: ", km.cluster_centers_)
print("labels: ", km.labels_)
mydict = {i: np.where(km.labels_ == i)[0] for i in range(km.n_clusters)}
print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
centroids:  [[0.78049437]
 [0.28805844]]
labels:  [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0]
{0: array([ 0,  1,  3,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 18, 20, 22, 23, 25, 28, 30, 31, 33,
       34, 35, 40, 42, 44, 49, 55, 57, 58, 59, 62, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 73,
       74, 78, 80, 86, 89, 91, 92, 96, 98, 99]), 1: array([ 2,  4,  8,  9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 24, 26, 27, 29, 32,
       36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 60,
       61, 63, 64, 65, 71, 72, 75, 76, 77, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 87, 88,
       90, 93, 94, 95, 97])}
```

In short, the key in the dictionary is now the cluster label which I want to be the cluster center. that looks something like below:

```
{0.78049437: array[0, 1, 3, 5..]}
{0.28805844: array[40, 42, 44, 49, ..]}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A small change to your dictionary comprehension should get you there:

```
my_dict = {km.cluster_centers_[i, 0]: np.where(km.labels_ == i)[0] for i in range(km.n_clusters)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that k-means focuses on finding the centers, not splitting thresholds. So it is not a particularly good method on 1d data (not os it fast, because the algorithms are designed for multivariate data). I would rather find minima in the kernel density estimation to identify splitting points, and describe the resulting ranges as (min,max) intervals.